# Need to list data from open weather map

Tags: javascript, ajax

i would like to list the data response from the current weather data(open weather map). I use a ajax xhttp request. I for loop and a variable called output to put the data from the for loop. I dont get any data in the output variable.

I have tried console.log for the data, which is parsed. And i get back some results. So the api works, it is only the for loop that does not work.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let output = "";
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(data);

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    output += '<li>' + data[i] + '</li>';
   }
   console.log(output);
   document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=London&appid=befb83bbddacf33f9ecfc1a5125d7201", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Weather api</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list">

</ul>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The API returns an object in the format

```js
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":anArray}
```

Since objects do not have a length property, your loop will never execute.

Presumably, you meant to iterate through the `.weather` property instead.
Try this:

```js
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let output = "";
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response).weather;
    console.log(data);

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    output += '<li>' + data[i] + '</li>';
   }
   console.log(output);
   document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
}
```

**EDIT**

Concatenating an object and a string implicitly calls the object's `toString` method that returns `[Object object]`. You should concatenate the string with the `.description` property instead.

Try this:

```js
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let output = "";
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response).weather;
    console.log(data);

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    output += '<li>' + data[i].description + '</li>';
   }
   console.log(output);
   document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you:) It is one step in right direction. I now get a list element in the html page. It says object. So i need to filter right.

Comment: How do i use the .description property?